# Javascript triggers again when back navigation is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an action that i only want to trigger once.

The problem is that upon the user pressing [back navigation], it gets triggered again.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(event){
  triggerActionOnlyOnce();
});
</script>
```

How do i tell the browser not to execute this comment if the user pressed "back?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the browser-mechanism to remember filled-in form-fields:

- Insert an text-input into the
  document and make it hidden using "display:none" 
   (doesn't work with `<input type="hidden">` )
- on ready first check the value, It should be empty:
- if it does, give
  it some value of your choice and call
  triggerActionOnlyOnce()
- if the value is not empty, the user came there using back/forward-> simply do nothing

Comment: that sounds like a great, easily implemented idea. thanks! i will try that right now

Answer (score 2):

It would be hard to catch any "back is pressed" action in all situations. I presume a "reload" of the page shouldn't retrigger the `triggerActionOnlyOnce()`?

What you can do, though not fully waterproof, is set something (session, cookie, etc) to remember the action was triggered and check for that.

Comment: a reload does not, because there is a backend flag. but a "back is pressed" does. I think a session/cookie makes sense. thanks!